# Difference between codec and converters in Spring Data Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

What's the main difference between `Codec` and `Converter`s in Spring Data Cassandra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL; DR;

[`TypeCodec`s](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/TypeCodec.html) are part of DataStax's Java Cassandra driver. `Converter`'s are Spring-specific to convert values *on top* of a driver.

### TypeCodec

They are used to serialize/deserialize values using the Cassandra protocol:

> A Codec that can serialize and deserialize to and from a given CQL type and a given Java Type.

Codecs are primarily used along with data types that map natively to Java types, such as `INT` to `integer` and `VARCHAR` to `String`.

A codec can also be used to map a UDT (represented as [`UDTValue`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/UDTValue.html)) to a POJO using DataStax [annotation-based Mapping add-on](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/be7bad8cdecb4fd69c58804e890eae14a78b146b/driver-mapping) without requiring you to copy UDT values to POJO properties in your code.

### Spring Data

Speaking of Spring Data for Apache Cassandra, it puts a layer of abstraction on top of the Cassandra driver. Spring Data handles object mapping and many more things that you don't get natively from the driver. Spring Data uses converters to convert a `ResultSet` [`Row`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Row.html) to an object. Approaching conversion with conventions, you get a defaulted mapping behavior which does not require you to provide additional converters in the first place.

If you want to customize Spring Data's conversion, then you can provide a custom [`Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.custom-converters) to, e.g., convert JSON (stored as String) to an object or to store data types in Cassandra that would naturally not be serializable using Spring Data's default object mapping.

Comment: I want to save the java object as json on cassandra and map the json value to java object, how to achieve this through spring data converter or TypeCodecs.

Comment: If you're using Spring Data, use `Converter`. See documentation. If you don't use Spring Data, use `TypeCodec`.

Comment: I referred your examples on github and tried Spring Data, I created table on cassandra with columns datatype as text. I used custom conversions to mapping the object. while saving into db got exception as "Value 2 of type class com.domain.DQuoteDetails does not correspond to any CQL3 type;".

Comment: Here are links to some examples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/cassandra/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/cassandra/convert and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/cassandra/example/src/test/java/example/springdata/cassandra/convert/ConversionIntegrationTests.java.

Comment: The java driver does natively provide the Row->Object mapping capabilities as well with the object mapper.

Comment: I tried using datastax cassandra driver, its converts row to object mapping as well as object to json also. Thanks lot